# What is the behaviour of int &a = *b?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

For example, I have the following codes:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int *c = &a;
int &d = *c;
c = &b;
d++;
```

What is behaviour of line 4? If i want a reference to a pointer,is it correct to use

```
int *&e = c;
```

Is there any reason why to choose a reference to a pointer?

Comment: These are several questions ... choose one.

Comment: _"Is there any reason why to choose a reference to a pointer?"_ yes if you want to modify the pointer, or observe changes to it.

Comment: Programming by guessing does not work. Did your dog eat your C++ book?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This declaration

```
int &d = *c;
```

declares a reference that refers the object pointed to by pointer `c`.

When this declaration was executed pointer `c` pointed to object `a`

```
int *c = &a;
```

So the referecne `d` refers object `a`. References may not be reassigned. They shall be initialized when they are declared.

Thus the expression in statement

```
d++;
```

increases object a.

You may declare a reference to a pointer.

This declaration

```
int *&e = c;
```

is valid.

Constant references can be bound to a temporary object. You may not take an address of a temporary object. Refrences alow to use more simple expressions.

Consider for example a simplified function `swap` that swaps two integers.

Using pointers the function would look like

```
void swap( int *a, int *b )
{
   int tmp = *a;
   *a = *b;
   *b = tmp;
}
```

and it could be called like

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;

swap( &a, &b );
```

Using references you could write the function the following way

```
void swap( int &a, int &b )
{
   int tmp = a;
   a = b;
   b = tmp;
}
```

and its call would look simpler than the call of the function with pointers.

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;

swap( a, b );
```

Answer (score 0):

1. regarding the meaning of line 4

   ```
   int a = 1;
   int*c = &a;    // okay:  pointer to int, points to a
   int&d = *c;    // okay;  reference to int, refers to *c=a;
   ```
2. A reference to a pointer is useful as argument to a function that may alter its value (=address pointed to), for example

   ```
   void allocate(int*&p)
   { p=new int[10]; }
   ```

Comment: @AisenWang If this answer was helpful, please accept it (click the tick) and/or upvote it (click the upward arrow)

Comment: I will. I need to wait for 6 minutes to do it.